# For how long does one have the right to say "patent pending" after submitting a provisional patent application in the United States?

Tags: uspto, provisional-application, usa, patent-pending

I read on https://www.legalzoom.com/sem/ip/patents.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20211008084401/https://www.legalzoom.com/sem/ip/patents.html)):

[image]

For how long does one have the right to say "patent pending" after submitting a provisional patent application in the United States?

Answer (score 2):

There is a $500 per incident penalty for false patent marking. If a application is no longer pending then it would be a false marking to mark newly produced items  with that mark. Of course you can file a non provisional at the end of the year or even another provisional application.

The law https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/292

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if there is a legal aspect, but for me you have a patent pending if you have an active application in process. From the [USPTO site](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/basics/types-patent-applications/provisional-application-patent).

> A provisional application for patent has a pendency lasting 12 months
> from the date the provisional application is filed. The 12-month
> pendency period cannot be extended. Therefore, an applicant who files
> a provisional application must file a corresponding nonprovisional
> application for patent (nonprovisional application) during the
> 12-month pendency period of the provisional application in order to
> benefit from the earlier filing of the provisional application

So for provisional applications that would be for one year from the filing date. If you followed up with a non provisional application you could continue to claim patent pending until a patent is issued or until the application process ends for any reason such as rejection or abandonment.